# Hypothesis testing, chance

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

To find out whether the inhabitants of two South Pacific islands may be regarded as having the same racial ancestry, an anthropologist determines the cephalie indices of six adult
males from each island, getting $x_1$ = 77.4 and $x_2$ = 72.2 and the corresponding standard
deviation $s_1 = 3.3$ and $s_2 = 2.1$. Test at $0.01$ level of significance whether the difference between the two sample means can reasonably be attributed to chance. Assume that the
populations sampled are normal and have equal variances.

I am confused on what the hypotheses should be: should it be $H_0: \mu_1 - \mu_2 = 0$ and $H_1: \mu_1-\mu_2 \neq 0$?

Comment: Seems to me your hypothesis and alternative are correct. Do you have difficulty doing the test? If so, please show where you get stuck.

Comment: Ok that's good to know, just wanted to make sure because I do the calculations

Comment: I got a $t$ value of $3.26>3.169$ which means the null hypothesis must be rejected. That means the difference of the sample means can't be attributed to chance right?

Comment: Thank you for showing your work. On this site, it is always best to show what you have done. See my Answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Pooled 2-sample t test.** Minitab is one of the relatively few statistical packages
that will perform a pooled 2-sample t test on summarized data
(that is, without seeing the 12 actual data values). You
have correctly used 6 + 6 -2 = 10 degrees of freedom to get
your critical value 3.169. Also, Minitab gets $T = 3.26$ for the test
statistic, which agrees with your result.
Here is Minitab output.

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample  N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       6  77.40   3.30      1.3
2       6  72.20   2.10     0.86

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  5.20
95% CI for difference:  (1.64, 8.76)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
  T-Value = 3.26  P-Value = 0.009  DF = 10
Both use Pooled StDev = 2.7659
```

**Welch 2-sample t-test.** However, as a matter of statistical practice, I would not be willing
to assume the two population variances are equal. (If the population
*means* might be different, why not also the population *variances*?)
The Welch version of the 2-sample t test does not assume equal
population variances. Standard statistical practice is not to assume
equal variances unless you have strong prior evidence of equality. (In this
situation, that might come from measuring cephalic indexes for many other
Pacific islands and having found that means vary, but that variances don't.)

Typically the Welch 2-sample t test uses a reduced degrees of freedom
to compensate for possibly unequal variances. A formula involving sample
sizes and sample standard deviations is used to find the adjusted degrees
of freedom. Here is Minitab output for the Welch 2-sample t test.

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample  N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       6  77.40   3.30      1.3
2       6  72.20   2.10     0.86

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  5.20
95% CI for difference:  (1.52, 8.88)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
  T-Value = 3.26  P-Value = 0.012  DF = 8
```

Notice that df = 8 here instead of 10 for the pooled test.
Also, notice that there is no note at the end about using
a pooled standard deviation. The P-value is a little larger
for the Welch test, but is still below 0.05, so $H_0$ is
rejected here as well.

Comment: If down-voters have non-whimsical reasons and the ability (or coursge?) to express them, I'll try to clarify the answer. For now, I see no reason to make changes.